# how to avoid blocking from the read function?

Tags: c, serial-port

I am trying to write and read data from an USB port in a cygwin command central. 
I have managed to write and read data when the device is connected but I want a way to detect if the other device isn't present or is unable ta send back any data. My current test code is shown below(I have tried a bunch of different things but nothing seemed to work).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "USB_com.h"
#include "unistd.h"
void main()
{
  int fd, value, bytes_read, bytes_written, nbytes, i, j;
  char buffR[20];
  char buffS[20];
  fd = USB_init("/dev/com1");
  printf("enter a message (write exit to terminate the session): ");
  fgets(buffS, 19, stdin);
  while (strncmp("exit", buffS, 4) != 0)
  {
    bytes_written = write(fd, buffS, 19);
    sleep(1);
    bytes_read = read(fd, buffR, 19);
    printf("string recieved : %s\n", buffR);
    memset(buffS, '\0', 19);
    printf("enter a message (write exit to terminate the session): ");
    fgets(buffS, 19, stdin);
  }
  USB_cleanup(fd);
}
```

And my USB_init.c for writing and reading from the USB device is shown below.

```
#include "USB_init.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/* baudrate settings are defined in <asm/termbits.h>, which is
 * included by <termios.h> */
#ifndef BAUDRATE
#define BAUDRATE B9600
#endif

#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1     /* POSIX compliant source */

static int fd, c, res;
static struct termios oldtio, newtio;
static char *device;

int USB_init(char *modemdevice)
{
    /* 
     * Open modem device for reading and writing and not as controlling tty
     * because we don't want to get killed if linenoise sends CTRL-C.
     **/
    device = modemdevice;
    //fd = open (device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    fd = open (device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fd < 0)
      {
      perror (device);
      exit(-1);
      }

    tcgetattr (fd, &oldtio);    /* save current serial port settings */
    bzero (&newtio, sizeof (newtio));   /* clear struct for new port settings */

    /* 
     *BAUDRATE: Set bps rate. You could also use cfsetispeed and cfsetospeed.
     *CRTSCTS : output hardware flow control (only used if the cable has
     *all necessary lines. )
     *CS8     : 8n1 (8bit,no parity,1 stopbit)
     *CLOCAL  : local connection, no modem contol
     *CREAD   : enable receiving characters
     **/
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

    /*
     *IGNPAR  : ignore bytes with parity errors
     *ICRNL   : map CR to NL (otherwise a CR input on the other computer
     *          will not terminate input)
     *          otherwise make device raw (no other input processing)
     **/
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;

    /*
     * Map NL to CR NL in output.
     *                  */
#if 0
    newtio.c_oflag = ONLCR;
#else
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
#endif


    /*
     * ICANON  : enable canonical input
     *           disable all echo functionality, and don't send signals to calling program
     **/
#if 1
    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;
#else
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
#endif

    /* 
     * initialize all control characters 
     * default values can be found in /usr/include/termios.h, and are given
     * in the comments, but we don't need them here
     *                                       */
    newtio.c_cc[VINTR] = 0; /* Ctrl-c */
    newtio.c_cc[VQUIT] = 0; /* Ctrl-\ */
    newtio.c_cc[VERASE] = 0;    /* del */
    newtio.c_cc[VKILL] = 0; /* @ */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOF] = 4;  /* Ctrl-d */
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* inter-character timer unused*/
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;  /* blocking read until 1 character arrives*/
    newtio.c_cc[VSWTC] = 0; /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VSTART] = 0;    /* Ctrl-q */
    newtio.c_cc[VSTOP] = 0; /* Ctrl-s */
    newtio.c_cc[VSUSP] = 0; /* Ctrl-z */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL] = 0;  /* '\0' */
    newtio.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;  /* Ctrl-r */
    newtio.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;  /* Ctrl-u */
    newtio.c_cc[VWERASE] = 0;   /* Ctrl-w */
    newtio.c_cc[VLNEXT] = 0;    /* Ctrl-v */
    newtio.c_cc[VEOL2] = 0; /* '\0' */

    /* 
     * now clean the modem line and activate the settings for the port
     **/
    tcflush (fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    /*
     * terminal settings done, return file descriptor
     **/

    return fd;
}

void USB_cleanup(int ifd){
    if(ifd != fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WARNING! file descriptor != the one returned by serial_init()\n");
    }
    /* restore the old port settings */
    tcsetattr (ifd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can do something like read(fd,buffR,19) but abort it after some time if I haven't recieved any data and print something like
printf("no contact with the device")?

I am extremely thankful for any suggestions on how to solve this!

Comment: *"I am trying to write and read data from an USB port"* -- If you're using a USB-to-RS232 adapter (or a USB gadget that emulates a serial port device), then the fact that the USBus is involved is totally transparent to the application program. So naming your functions **USB_init()** and **USB_cleanup()** when they do nothing with respect to USB is misleading. `bzero (&newtio, sizeof (newtio))` is a common but wrong method of initializing a **termios** structure. Study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Comment: @sawdust - you are of course generally right about the misuse of the USB label with what is a serial API, but it is worth remembering that USB serial converters are not, in fact totally transparent - they are packetized transport devices with substantial latency, a difference which can have practical impact on application programs and protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with serials, you have two options: either use `select`/`poll` with timeout, or configure the port using termios.

For `select` and `poll`, the approach is first wait for event on descriptor and read *after* successful result. Pro of this method is that it works also with network sockets and some other descriptor types:

```
int fd = ...
fd_set fds;
stuct timeval timeout;

timeout.tv_sec = 10; /* timeout in secs */
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&fds)
FD_SET(fd, &fds)
if (select(fd, fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0)
  read(...)
else ... timeout
```

The `poll` example is very similar to above.

But, when working with any kind of serial devices, there is another way of making read to time out correctly. You need to use `VMIN` and `VTIME` attributes:

```
newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = timeout; /* timeout in 1/10 of second  1==100ms, 10==1sec*/
newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
```

That is it.

Comment: Second part of answer is incomplete and misleading.  **VMIN** and **VTIME** are only salient when non-canonical input mode is used.

Comment: @sawdust What do you mean by non-canonical input mode?

Comment: @SubinSebastian -- See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

Comment: Anyone using this in a loop should be wary to reset ```timeout.tv_sec``` and ```timeout.tv_usec``` each iteration. The last paragraph of [select(2) The timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html#DESCRIPTION) details how Linux alters these values.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to take a look at [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to monitor the file descriptor for being ready to be read from. It could be called with a time-out.

Or make the file describtor [non-blocking when `open()`ing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) it or later using [`fcntl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html), so it will return from [`read()` with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) if no data is available, which would allow you to implement your on logic to decide when to retry or to cancel reading.

Comment: It says ` Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and block devices;` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: @shaoyihe: Linking the Linux man-pages in a Cygwin context probably was not a good idea. The POSIX documentation is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html It specifies the case of non-/blocking differently.